# How to use jquery ui autocomplete with different callback name with remote source

Tags: jquery-ui, autocomplete, jsonp

I am following [this](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp) example to get JSONP data from remote server. jQuery append its own callback function while sending request like
 `http://url.com?callback=jQuery17107389513931702822_1332765044455&_=1332765051700`

But the source is replying JSONP data in a fixed format as **REPYL$queryString({"data":"abc"})** where queryString is the string for which reply is generated.
How to customize the options to support my own callback name? The error which I am getting right now is

```
 Uncaught ReferenceError: REPLY$querystring is not defined.
```

UPDATE

setting which worked for me are:

```
jsonp:false,
jsonpCallback:"CALL_BACK_NAME",
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `jsonp` setting in the `.ajax` request of [the example you are using](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp):

**jsonp**

> Override the callback function name in a jsonp request. This value will be used instead of 'callback' in the 'callback=?' part of the query string in the url. So {jsonp:'onJSONPLoad'} would result in 'onJSONPLoad=?' passed to the server. As of jQuery 1.5, setting the jsonp option to false prevents jQuery from adding the "?callback" string to the URL or attempting to use "=?" for transformation. In this case, you should also explicitly set the jsonpCallback setting. For example, { jsonp: false, jsonpCallback: "callbackName" }

```
jsonp: 'YOUR-CALLBACK-NAME'
```

See the [`.ajax` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: Reading the given documentation further my code is working with setting jsonp:false, jsonpCallback:"callbackname". though the jquery is still appending some random string in data but its working :)